# Preload function fail to fetch

Tags: json, p5.js, preload

I'm try to learn about data visualization and I found an online course on youtube. 
I'm coping the code of the lesson trying to call a .json file from the sketch.js, but I'm stuck with an infinite loading page. 
I think the problem is in the preload function and I don't understand what am doing wrong.

This is the sketch.js

```
var data;

function preload() {
    data = loadJSON("birds.json");
}

function setup() {
    noCanvas();
    var bird = data.birds[1].members[2];
    createP(bird);
}
```

This is the .json file, validated online so it should work:

```
{
  "description": "Birds of Antarctica, grouped by family",
  "source": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_birds_of_Antarctica",
  "birds": [
    {
      "family": "Albatrosses",
      "members": [
        "Wandering albatross",
        "Grey-headed albatross",
        "Black-browed albatross",
        "Sooty albatross",
        "Light-mantled albatross"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Cormorants",
      "members": [
        "Antarctic shag",
        "Imperial shag",
        "Crozet shag"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Diving petrels",
      "members": [
        "South Georgia diving petrel",
        "Common diving petrel"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Ducks, geese and swans",
      "members": [
        "Yellow-billed pintail"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Gulls",
      "members": [
        "Kelp gull"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Penguins",
      "members": [
        "King penguin",
        "Emperor penguin",
        "Gentoo penguin",
        "Adelie penguin",
        "Chinstrap penguin",
        "Rockhopper penguin",
        "Macaroni penguin"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Shearwaters and petrels",
      "members": [
        "Antarctic giant petrel",
        "Hall's giant petrel",
        "Southern fulmar",
        "Antarctic petrel",
        "Cape petrel",
        "Snow petrel",
        "Great-winged petrel",
        "White-headed petrel",
        "Blue petrel",
        "Broad-billed prion",
        "Salvin's prion",
        "Antarctic prion",
        "Slender-billed prion",
        "Fairy prion",
        "Grey petrel",
        "White-chinned petrel",
        "Kerguelen petrel",
        "Sooty shearwater"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Sheathbills",
      "members": [
        "Snowy sheathbill"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Skuas and jaegers",
      "members": [
        "South polar skua",
        "Brown skua"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Storm petrels",
      "members": [
        "Grey-backed storm petrel",
        "Wilson's storm petrel",
        "Black-bellied storm petrel"
      ]
    },
    {
      "family": "Terns",
      "members": [
        "Arctic tern",
        "Antarctic tern"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And last, this is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What is `crearP`? It doesn't seem to be one of [the p5.js global functions](https://p5js.org/reference/). (Your use of `loadJSON` and `data` looks fine, and `bird` should get the value `"Crozet shag"` [remember array indexes start at 0]...)

Comment: I misspelled here but in the code is: createP

Comment: Okay, what is `createP`? It doesn't seem to be one of [the p5.js global functions](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Comment: You are right. I was just testing the code so I didn't check. In a previous video  it was explain that "createP" was a way to create html element in Javascript. What function can I use instead in order to display the text in the variable?

Comment: Please open up your [developer tools](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/javascript/developer-tools) and look at the JavaScript console to check for errors. If you still can't get it working, please post a link to your code running in [the P5.js editor](https://editor.p5js.org).

Answer (score 2):

I've quickly ran your code and it's returning "Crozet shag" so looks fine. I was using VS Code and loaded it up in Live Server.

I don't think there's anything wrong with what you're doing but it sounds like there's an issue with your environment.

Some functionality (loading external files, for example) works as expected when the files are placed online but if you try to view them locally, you see some kind of "cross-origin" errors in the console. Are you using a local web server? This might solve your problems.

Comment: Thank you for all the answer. So I'm starting to think that the problem is indeed the environment. So, if I run the code opening the index file from chrome this is what I get: [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/i26ijjS.png). 

I tried to follow the indication to use a local server and It works only if I change the last line of code in the sketch.js into text(). 

I'll try the same code on a different machine to see if it works.

Thank you for the help.